# Alternative for templates in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, templates

I wrote code that looked like the following:

```
template<typename CocoaWidget>
class Widget : boost::noncopyable
{
private:
  CocoaWidget* mCocoaWidget;

public:
  Widget()
  {
    mCocoaWidget = [[CocoaWidget alloc] init];
  }

  // ...
};

class Button : Widget<NSButton>
{
  // ...
};
```

But that doesn't work, because Mac Dev Center says:

> Objective-C classes, protocols, and
>   categories cannot be declared inside a
>   C++ template

So what shall I do now best?

Comment: Why do you insist on using C++?

Comment: Because I want a C++ wrapper for some cocoa classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you can't do this (have you tried)?

The quote from Mac Dev Center says you can't declare an Objective-C *class* inside a template. What you're doing, however, is merely declaring a *pointer to an Objective-C object* inside a template -- quite a different thing, and I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be allowed (though I have never tried).

Comment: I think, you are right. I tested the simplified example and it compiles. I just got  `invalid use of incomplete type ‘class widget<NSButton>’` so i thought that would be the problem. So probably the mistake is anywhere else. Thanks though!

Comment: @Niels: If you get that error message, the problem is probably that you aren't including the header file with the definition of your `Widget<CocoaWidget>` template class.

Comment: No. I just forgot anywhere a closing bracket. I've solved it no (Why can't gcc just say that I forgot a closing }???

Comment: @Niels: That's typical of gcc, unfortunately. Clang (clang.llvm.org) will hopefully fix this...

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong? Your code is working. My similar test case compiled and run without leaks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

template <typename T>
class U {
protected:
        T* a;
public:
        U() { a = [[T alloc] init]; }
        ~U() { [a release]; }
};

class V : U<NSMutableString> {
public:
        V(int i) : U<NSMutableString>() { [a appendFormat:@"%d = 0x%x\n", i, i]; }
        void print() const { NSLog(@"%@", a); }
};

int main() {
        U<NSAutoreleasePool> p;
        V s(16);
        s.print();
        return 0;
}
```